# join table cell values and reformat by javascript

Tags: javascript

sample: https://jsfiddle.net/5q9tddsh/

```
<table width="100%" >
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>id</td>
            <td>book</td>
            <td>colour</td>
            <td>name</td>
            <td>public</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Book1</td>
            <td>Red</td>
            <td>This is a book one</td>
            <td>#number1111111</td>
        </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Book2</td>
            <td>White</td>
            <td>This is a book two</td>
            <td>#number2222222</td>
        </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Book3</td>
            <td>Blue</td>
            <td>This is a book three</td>
            <td>#number33333333</td>
        </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Book4</td>
            <td>Yellow</td>
            <td>This is a book four</td>
            <td>#number44444444</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


const table= document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0], 
      tableRow = table.querySelectorAll('tr');

tableRow.forEach((v, i) => {
  v.querySelectorAll('td').forEach((v, i) => {
    console.log(v); 
  });

});
```

How can I join each `tr` values and seperated them by a "`:`", and each `tr` has a new line. I am stuck on joining them
so look like below:

```
id:book:colour:name:public (start a new line '\n')
1:Book1:Red:This is a book one:#number1111111 (newline)

....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map over the elements and join them

```js
const table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0],
  tableRow = Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('tr'));

let data = tableRow.map(v => {
  return Array.from(v.getElementsByTagName('td')).map(x => x.innerText).join(":");
}).join("\n");

console.log(data);
```

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>id</td>
      <td>book</td>
      <td>colour</td>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>public</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Book1</td>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>This is a book one</td>
      <td>#number1111111</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Book2</td>
      <td>White</td>
      <td>This is a book two</td>
      <td>#number2222222</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Book3</td>
      <td>Blue</td>
      <td>This is a book three</td>
      <td>#number33333333</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Book4</td>
      <td>Yellow</td>
      <td>This is a book four</td>
      <td>#number44444444</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```